# ElasticSearch Watcher filtered range query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need help in writing Watcher input query for ElasticSearch (v5.3). My requirement is to trigger alert if apache status code becomes 500 or more.

`Index name: Apache-access-log
Field name: status_code
Kibana Discover query: status_code: [500 TO 600]
Time period: Last 15 minutes.`

Here is the Watcher input query that I have used, but it didn't worked as expected.

```
{
  "search": {
    "request": {
      "index": [
        "Apache-access-log"
      ],
      "body": {
        "query": {
          "filtered": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "status_code: 500",
              }
            },
            "filter": {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "now-15m",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch 5.5 does not support a filtered query anymore. Use a boolean query with a filter

bool:
  must:
    query_string:
      query: 'status_code:[500:600]'
  filter:
    range:
      @timestamp: ...

Always try to query as a standalone query first, before putting it into watcher. If you have some time I highly encourage you [this blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/watching-the-watches-writing-debugging-and-testing-watches) how to write and debug watches